# Fatal errors in Catalog Observer in EE 1.14

Tags: error, magento-enterprise, bug

Just upgraded my dev site to EE 1.14 and am seeing two fatal errors in the Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer - is there a place to submit a patch / inform Magento? I found this bug reporter:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/report/

but there's nothing for EE.

Specifically, line 215 should be checking for the existence of $block ($block was empty, triggering the fatal), and line 241, checking for the existence of $menuBlock (same).

Comment: When exactly does this error happen? Do you have any custom code/themes that could be causing this error?

Comment: Error being triggered on the home page load - and yes - using a custom theme. I'll trace up a bit & see if I can see where addCatalogToTopmenuItems is being called.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options.

1. Since I think it could be an issue with your custom theme then you can contact that developer yourself and inform them you are having issues with 1.14. If you created the theme yourself then have a look into which parts are actually causing this issue.
2. Since the code is not part of EE specifically you can raise a bug in the link you mentioned: http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/report/
3. EE should come with some form of support package so you should have someone you can contact directly about this issue,

If it is not an issue with the design and really a problem with the code then I would create a patch, and put it somewhere like github and share it around as you never know who else could be having this issue.

Sorry that this is not a 100% an answer but without some more information about your code and theme etc. it would be hard to answer.

Answer (score 0):

We were using custom code overriding the core Page Block Html Topmenu. I compared to the new core version and updated the custom code to properly pass the 'block' object to the array.